# Wordpress Development understanding core

Tags: plugins

Just like any other framework, I preassume that Wordpress is a framework that should be understood before any further development should take place.

I am keen to know about the recommended steps to understand Wordpress.

I am coming from .Net technology with more than 10 years of programming experience. I know how wordpress external. However, I want to know about internals' so that I can build my own plugins and stuff like that.

Since it is the community dedicated to Wordpress development, I would like to know the best possible way of understanding internals and then write plugins.

I just need a direction, I will find my way.

thank you,
Mr. Codebased.

Comment: I'd recommend reading some of Tom McFarlin's excellent articles, like ["The Beginner's Guide to WordPress Actions and Filters"](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373) or [Using WordPress for Web Application Development: Understanding Events, Actions, and Filters](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-wordpress-for-web-application-development-understanding-events-actions-and-filters--wp-34113). It certainly doesn't tell you the whole story to understand WordPress, but they cover important parts.

Comment: Had you visited http://codex.wordpress.org